# Powershell: Get-MsalToken error AADSTS7000218

Tags: powershell, access-token

Running the following Powershell command

```
$tokenresponse = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -TenantId $tenantID -Interactive  -RedirectUri "http://localhost"
```

gives me the error:

```
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
```

All solutions I found are pointing to the direction, that in the Azure Protal I should enable "Allow public client flows" but this setting is enabled. Any idea how I can get the token (I would need to get a token for delegated permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but my answer below might help someone in the future. I ran into this same problem today and the way to fix it was by correcting the configuration on the App Registration. The solution was quite simple. I just had to set up Authentication to the right platform: "Mobile and **desktop applications**". Instead of Web or SPA.

[image]

To test it, get your tenant id and application (client) id, and pass it to the Get-MsalToken commandlet like below. The login page should pop-up, including any MFA dialogs (if MFA is configured).

```
$tenant_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000"
$client_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000"

$authParams = @{
     ClientId    = $client_id
     TenantId    = $tenant_id
     Interactive = $true
}

$auth = Get-MsalToken @authParams
$auth
```

Comment: While looking for a solution to this issue, I also found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573253/get-msaltoken-error-aadsts7000218-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-p . But it did not work for me.