# Get-MsalToken error AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Here is my PowerShell script

```
$connectionDetails = @{
    'TenantId'    = '****-****'
    'ClientId'    = '****-****'
    'Interactive' = $true
    'Scopes' = '****-****'
    'RedirectUri' = '****-****'
}

$token = Get-MsalToken @connectionDetails

$accessToken = $token.AccessToken

write-output $accessToken
```

It errors out as follows:

> AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve the error "AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client\_secret or client\_assertion'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609432/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-aadsts70002-the-request-body-must-contain-the-follo)

Answer (score 16):

Please see [the differences between public client and confidential client applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications).

Confidential client applications are safe to keep application secrets while public clients not.

So the error you encountered means that your app registration is Confidential client application (when you create it, you select **Web**) which requires you to provide `ClientSecret`, but you didn't specify it.

[image]

So you have 2 options to resolve it.

The first one is providing `ClientSecret` in your script (**don't modify anything on Azure portal**):

```
$connectionDetails = @{
    'TenantId'    = '****-****'
    'ClientId'    = '****-****'
    'ClientSecret'= '****-****'
    'Interactive' = $true
    'Scopes' = '****-****'
    'RedirectUri' = '****-****'
}
```

The second one is changing your app registration from Confidential client application to
Public client app on Azure portal -> your app registration -> manifest. (**don't modify your script**)

[image]

The [Get-MsalToken.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.2.1.1/Content/Get-MsalToken.ps1) also includes the 2 examples:

```
.EXAMPLE
    PS C:\>Get-MsalToken -ClientId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -TenantId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -Interactive -Scope 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read' -LoginHint user@domain.com
    Force interactive authentication to get AccessToken (with MS Graph permissions User.Read) and IdToken for specific Azure AD tenant and UPN using client id from application registration (public client).

.EXAMPLE
    PS C:\>Get-MsalToken -ClientId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -ClientSecret (ConvertTo-SecureString 'SuperSecretString' -AsPlainText -Force) -TenantId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -Scope 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    Get AccessToken (with MS Graph permissions .Default) and IdToken for specific Azure AD tenant using client id and secret from application registration (confidential client).
```

Comment: I am curious why you recommend changing this in the Manifest section rather than through the UI in the Authentication section? Why risk making a typo or transcription error when Microsoft provides a button/toggle option you can click to set this to true?

Comment: Hi; I was experiencing the same error message. I tried your suggestion (and I'm puzzled as user @TylerH about how to change this parameter via menu/toggle option) and now I'm getting a AADSTS65001.